Avoid duplicate team member on Opportunity record
How to avoid adding duplicate team member when adding Opportunity Split record on Opportunity record. I dont think this can be done via validation rule so need help to implement this via apex
tried validation rule and expecting this via apex trigger

Can you [edit] your question and add your code for this as a [mcve]? If it doesn't really involve code, it's probably off-topic here (check the [help/on-topic]), but it may fit [salesforce.se]. (Check their help pages on what their scope is and what details you need to add to your question.)
